# Delphi: create a TListItemTextButton on runtime in a mobile app

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I have a ListView and I create items at runtime. In one of these items, depending on some condition, I want to insert an item with only the button and its properties like text, width, color and so on.

I have something like this:

```
var MyListView: TListView;
    Item: TListViewItem;
    LinkButton: TlistItemTextButton;

...
Item := MyListView.Items.Add;
Item.Purpose := TListItemPurpose.None;
if Item.Objects.FindObject('MyButton') = nil then
begin
  LinkButton := TListItemTextButton.Create(Item);
  LinkButton.Text := 'MyText';           
  LinkButton.Width := 300;
  LinkButton.Name := 'MyButton';
  LinkButton.Visible := True;
  LinkButton.OnSelect := MyLinkClickProc;
  Item.Objects.Add(LinkButton);
end;
...
```

The app compiles and runs on my iOS device but the button is not shown. I have the same issue if I create the button at design time with `Visibile := False` and I change the `Visible` property to `True` with something like this.

```
Item.Objects.FindObjectT<TListItemText>('MyButton').Visible := True;
```

It doesn't work.

Any idea where the problem may be caused?

Comment: In the ListView there's a property called ItemAppearance. In that, there's a sub-property also called ItemAppearance. I believe it may need to be set to DynamicAppearance in order to achieve what you want

Comment: When asking about FMX (Firemonkey), it helps if you also add a tag for the specific Delphi version you're using, as those components change very rapidly, often with extreme changes that can drastically alter the code and break existing code. I added the Firemonkey tag, but I don't know what Delphi version you're actually using. You may want to add it to improve your chances of getting an answer.

Comment: Thanks Dave, I supposed that too but on checking the ListView already has this property.

Comment: Ken, thanks for your advice, I'm pretty new on Stackoverflow. It's on Delphi Tokyo 10.2.3.